# Set of roots of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p,q \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ be primes and let $W$ be the set of roots of $x^p-1$ in a finite extension $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$ of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. Show there exists a $r\in W$ such that $W = \{1,r,...,r^{p-1} \}$. I need to find the degree of $r$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ (I am thinking this is $p$) and show that $T = \sum_{x=0}^{p-1} r ^ {x^{2}}$ implies $T^2 = p$. Also, I need to prove that $T \in \mathbb{F}_{q} \iff q$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Comment: Have you been told that $x^p-1$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$?

Comment: I think $x^p-1$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement of this problem seems to allow $[\mathbb{F}_{Q}:\mathbb{F}_{q}]=1$, in which case the result is false. So I shall assume that there is at least one root $\ne 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$.

The roots of $W$ clearly form a group under multiplication in $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$. As a subgroup of a cyclic group they must themselves form a cyclic group. Let $r\ne 1$ be a generator of this group.

$r^i$ is also a root for  $i\in \{1,2,...,p-1 \}.$ If two of these roots, say $r^i$ and $r^j$, were equal then we would have $r^{i-j}=1$. Coupled with $r^p=1$ this would force $r=1$ or $p|i-j$. Thus $\{1,r,...,r^{p-1} \}$ is the full set of $p$ roots and this completes the first of the required results.

Note that just having one root not equal to $1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$ forced all the roots to be in $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$. Therefore $x^p-1=(x-1)(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+1)$ where the second factor is irreducible. The degree of $r$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ is therefore $p-1$.

Jumping to the final part of the question:-

Since $T^2=p$, $p$ is a quadratic residue mod $q$ and therefore, by quadratic reciprocity, $q$ is a quadratic residue mod $p.$

The part of the proof I have omitted is equivalent to the proof of the trig identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \cos (\frac{2\pi k^2}{p})=\sqrt p$$ for primes of the form $4t+1$.

Comment: How do I know that $(\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}r^{k^{2}})^2=p$?

Comment: That's a part of your problem that I've checked and it seems true. I have an idea about how to prove it but I haven't yet managed a complete proof.

Comment: Could you share the rough idea? Because I tried a geometric series approach but it does not seem to work.

Comment: As far as I can see this part has nothing to do with $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$ and therefore one can prove it over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think you want $(\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} cos(\frac{2\pi k^2}{p}))^{2} = p$

Comment: Yes - just a typo. There must be a nice proof of this result but I haven't found it!

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of the identity and what is the specific argument for how this applies to $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$?

Comment: Because of the irreducibility of the polynomial this question has been all about, the result for $T$ can only be true if squaring $T$ leads to terms which we can gather up into $p$ plus a multiple of $1+r+... +r^{p-1}$. This must equally be true over C where the polynomial is similarly irreducible. Therefore if one can spot a simple reason why it's true over C (where we have simple expressions for the roots) the same reason will work for your problem. I haven't spotted this result on the internet but there are loads of these trig expressions.

Comment: I suspect there will be something simple involving roots of an equation.